# How do I prove $a^3-b^3 \geq a^2b - b^2a$

Tags: inequality

Given that $a>b>0$, prove that $a^3-b^3 \geq a^2b - b^2a$.
I have considered difference of cubes, where $a^3-b^3 = (a-b)(a^2+ab+b^2)$. However this doesn't seem to get me that far - especially when working backwards from the statement I need to prove - where I factorised the right hand side into $ab(a-b)$ and equated with the expansion earlier, giving the following inequality: $a^2+ab+b^2 \geq ab$. However by AM-GM, it follows that $a^2+b^2 \geq 2ab$ which my statement above does not follow. Help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Left side minus right side is $a^3-a^2b+b^2a-b^3=a^2(a-b)+b^2(a-b)$.

Comment: $a^2+b^2\ge 2ab\implies a^2+ab+b^2\ge3ab\ge ab$, so you're already done with $a-b>0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that $a > b > 0$, we take

$$
S = a^3 - b^3, \ \ T = a^2 b - b^2 a = a b (a - b)
$$

Note that we can write
$$
S = a^3 - b^3 = (a - b) (a^2 + a b + b^2)
$$

Thus,
$$
S - T = (a - b) (a^2 + a b + b^2) - a b (a - b) = (a - b)(a^2 + b^2) > 0
$$
since $a > b > 0$.

Comment: Yes, I too got $(a-b)(a^2+b^2)>0$, however, I was uncertain as the question wanted $\geq$ not just >.

Comment: @Numenorean  you seem to have something backwards. The conclusion is that $S-T >0.$  This also implies $S-T \geq 0;$ thus $S-T \geq 0$  has been proved in the above answer

Comment: I thank you for the kind explanation!

Answer (score 0):

Alternative approach:

$0 < (a - b)^3 = (a^3 - b^3) - (3)(a^2b - ab^2) \implies$

$(a^3 - b^3) > 3(a^2b - ab^2).$

Further, since $a > b,$

you know that $a^2b > ab^2 \implies (a^2b - ab^2) > 0.$

Therefore $3(a^2b - ab^2) > (a^2b - ab^2)$.